# What is the German word for “binge”?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

I want to say the following in German:

> When children come home, they binge on screen time. [talking about mobile phones.]

But I can’t seem to find the appropriate word for *binge.* I've found words like *Fressgelage* and *Saufgelage* but they relate to eating/drinking.

Is there a general word/verb that means excessive usage (after not doing the action for a while)?

Would it be the word *Gelage?* If so, how would you relate it to phones? *Handygelage?* As the only options for *binge* I have found are nouns, what verb would you use with them? Or is there a verb that means *to binge?*

Currently I've come up with this alternative:

> Wenn Kinder nach Haus kommen, benutzen sie sofort ihre Handys, weil den ganzen Tag in der Schule sie verboten.

Would this be a good alternative?

Comment: The broadening of the meaning in English is relatively new, something similar has not happened in German.

Comment: I recommend **glotzen**, as for TV. It's derogative for *starren* – *to stare*. *Wenn die Kinder nach Hause kommen, **glotzen** sie gleich wieder in ihr Tablet.*

Comment: The sequence of words is wrong, "Wenn Kinder nach Haus kommen, benutzen sie sofort ihre Handys, weil sie den ganzen Tag in der Schule  verboten sind" is better.

Comment: I have always asked myself the same questions. Shame all the answers are related to this specific use case.

Comment: At least among the nerdier of my friends, we use the word "binge" itself for the act of watching many episodes of a TV series in one sitting. "Am Wochenende hab ich die siebte Staffel von Game of Thrones gebinget."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no word that can be universally used like "binge". As you already found out, there are different words for the different things you can do excessively. Up to my knowledge, however, there's no word that describes the excessive use of  mobile phones.

In principle, you could say "Sie benutzen ihr Handy exzessiv", but saying "Wenn Kinder nach Hause kommen, benutzen sie sofort ihre Handys exzessiv." sounds odd, as *exzessiv* is normally used to describe an action that lasts longer or is generally true. Saying

> Kinder, denen die Handynutzung in der Schule verboten ist, zeigen eine exzessivere Nutzung in ihrer Freizeit.

would be a fine way of saying it. It is definitely written language, though. If your sentence is more conversational, than there's nothing wrong with

> Wenn Kinder nach Haus kommen, benutzen sie sofort ihre Handys, weil *es ihnen* den ganzen Tag in der Schule *verboten ist*.

Comment: I think "exzessiv"  is a good general translation of "binge" in all contexts (even though the grammatical constructions a different). Which means that there is no translation actually, since "exzessiv" is the exact twin of "excessive".

Answer (score 22):

"Hängen" is often used in the consumer context of binging.  "Zu Hause hängen sie ständig am Computer/am Handy/vor der Glotze (TV set)".  An intentional/organized/prepared binging event is often titled "Marathon" with a qualifier, like a "Star-Wars-Marathon".

Comment: This is particularly good because "hängen" suggests "abhängig" (addicted), and that's just what *binging* implies as well.

Comment: Can hängen also be used about, for example, junk food or alcohol?

Comment: @Wilson Well, AFAIK hängen refers to the medium, not actually to the activity. So while you can say "Zu Hause hängen sie ständig am Handy" it is not referring to what is consumed through the mobile. So while you could for alcohol say "Er hängt leider an der Flasche" referring to something that is contained in the bottle implying making addicted, while saying "Er hängt am essen" or "Er hängt am Alkohol", while not being able to say its incorrect, I can tell you that feels odd to me.

Answer (score 12):

A word that fits well but would rarely be found in any dictionary is "suchteln" or "süchteln" or "suchten" (all derived from "Sucht" == addiction) that I tend to use for my kid's internet desires:

> Wenn meine Kinder nach Hause kommen, suchteln sie schon nach ihren Handys, weil die in der Schule verboten sind.

While *suchteln* and *suchten* might be very colloquial, *süchteln* is an old German word that would be understood as "binge" and can be found in some older dictionaries.

> SÜCHTELN, vb., iterativum zu 1suchten, süchten, 'kränkeln': sücklen, süchtlen zukkelen, ziekelyk zyn Kramer-Moerbeck neues dt.-holländ. wb. (1768) 334b; später, wohl direct aus 1sucht (III A 1 c) abgeleitet, 'in kleinlicher und lächerlicher weise nach etwas streben': für einen nach originalität süchtelnden narren Gutzkow (1872) 5, 74.

(Grimm's Wörterbuch)

Comment: Today, in most regions the `l` is left out: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suchten https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/6105-suchten http://www.sprachnudel.de/woerterbuch/suchten

Comment: Finde ich unpassend, denn zwischen Sucht und binge ist ein gewaltiger Unterschied.

Comment: I'd agree on *Sucht* being slightly misplaced, but *suchten* comes quite close.

Comment: @Robert Suchteln, is a much weaker form of addiction and generally perceived as harmless. For me it also carries the connotation of short bursts of excessive action throughout the day. So I think this is the most adequate translation in this context.

Answer (score 6):

> When children come home, they binge on screen time.

```
Wenn die Kinder nach Hause kommen, hängen sie am Handy/am Internet/am Bildschirm.
```

*Hängen* wird auch für anderes Suchtverhalten, für andere Abhängigkeiten verwendet, etwa an der Flasche hängen, an der Nadel hängen. Statt *hängen* drückt auch *kleben* eine intensive, schwer lösbare Bindung gut aus.

Eine Alternative wäre auch:

```
Wenn die Kinder nach Hause kommen, versinken sie ins Handy/ins  Internet.
```

*Eine exzessive Nutzung zeigen* ist ein sehr trockener, psychologischer oder soziologischer Sprachgebrauch.

Sie *... suchteln schon nach ihren Handys* drückt noch den Moment vor dem Gebrauch aus. Sonderlich verbreitet ist das Wort auch nicht.

*Glotzen* passt nur für 's Fernsehen, bei dem man nicht selbst aktiv ist, wie bei Smartphone oder Computer.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat informal expression that is more on the youth side of users, is "etwas suchten" - "Das Kind suchtet den ganzen Tag ein Computerspiel, Filme, etc"

Answer (score 0):

A word which perhaps can be used in some contexts is *Orgie.* I fits nicely because it is, like *Gelage,* also about gluttony but can be used metaphorically.

> Sobald die Kinder nach Hause kommen, geht wieder die Handy-Orgie los.

One problem with that is the sexual connotation and language level. *binge*, while being somewhat informal, can still be used in written language like a newspaper article. By contrast, *Orgie* in this metaphorical sense is probably restricted to more informal uses, probably only casual spoken German.

Answer (score -1):

[http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schwelgen][1]
The closest would be "schwelgen", I guess.